# Are there any good patterns for handling list of entities

Tags: domain-driven-design, entities

In "DDD" what is the best patterns for handling different versions of your entities, e.g. Entities in a list vs the full object. I would like to avoid the overhead of getting properties I do not need when displaying the entities in a list

Would you have a separate entity type used in lists or just fill up your full entity type partially?
Would you use inheritance?

Answer (score 0):

I understand your urge to create "views" of models in the domain, but would recommend against it. Personally, I use the entire entity inside of the domain, regardless of the situation. The entity is the entity, and anything less or more just does not feel clean.  That does not mean that I can't use a reference to the entity to help focus my use of the items in the list, though.

The entity does not cross the domain boundary in my implementation. Instead, I return a type of DTO and have application services that can abstract a view from it.  This allows, for example, allowing a presenter to generate the correct view model from a DTO and provide it to the view.  I don't know if you are talking about operations in the domain services or in the application services, but there are a couple of things you can do that could be applied to either (or both).

You can do certain things to reduce the performance penalty of working with the entire entity in the domain layers, as well.  One thing to look at is implementing some sort of cache-aside implementation.  When an entity is requested, check to see if it is cached.  If it is, return the cached version.  If it isn't, pull it and then cache it before returning.  When the entity is updated, evict it from the cache and do your update.  I have purposely created my concrete repository implementations to be cache-aware to facilitate this.  One other thing to consider using an approach like this is that it is beneficial to do as many fine-grained operations as possible.  While that seems illogical at first, if entities are commonly "gotten" from your data store, it is easy to set up some logging to measure the number of cache hits to cache misses.

Coming full circle, to your question...  Most lists I deal with are small, so I incur the penalty of loading up the entity in its entirety.  Assuming that most use cases will involve the user drilling into one or more of the items, they are pre-cached because of the cache-aside implementation.  The number of items is fluid, but I generally apply this approach to anything less than twenty five entities in a list.

For larger lists, I just use IDs.  Most likely, the use case here is some sort of search result.  Search results are commonly paged, for example, and this does not fit into the above pattern.  Instead, I use the larger list of IDs as a sliding range window of entities I am interested in that I then pass to a GetRangeById() method that all of my repositories have - written to purposely take a list of identifiers and load them one at a time so they are cached.  In essence, this will take a larger lightweight list and zero in just on the area I am interested in at a given point in time.

With an approach like this, the important thing to realize is that it is highly scalable.  It might not baseline as fast as a non-cached approach with small sets of data, but will perform better with larger sets of data.  There is an implied performance overhead of operation at play here, but it degrades at a slower rate than a standard "load 'em up" pattern, as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CQRS pattern to separate query processing and command processing. And you can do it even on a single database. In such a case you would map you view models directly to the tables in databse (via NHibernate for example). Commands (writes) would go through real domain model and would be persisted in the DB. Queries (like get me a list of entities) would bypass the domain a go straight do DB. There is no point in querying domain object because you actually don't invoke any business logic in them, just retrieving some data.

You can also extend this solution to full-featured CQRS by having separate stores for command side and for query side. Query side would be synchronized by means of replication or pub/sub messaging.